# If I put two different dictionaires into a list. I get wrong result. One Dictionary is overwritting the keys/values from the other in the list

Tags: python, dictionary, maya

I am writing my own rigging framework in maya for learning purposes. And one of the essential thing of my framework is collecting meta data from the scene and put that into a dictionary. So that you can rebuild the rig from that dictionary.

In one method I want to put two dictionaries into a list. But when I do that, it seems that one is overwriting the values of the keys! Like I would use the update function for a dictionary.

Here are the two dictionaries:

```
{nt.RootOpMetaNode(u'M_ROOT_op_0_METAND'): [{'component_type': u'single_control', 'component_side': u'M', 'main_op_nd_ws_matrix': Matrix([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]), 'sub_op_nd_ws_matrix': [], 'connection_types': [u'translate', u'rotate', u'scale'], 'ik_spaces_ref': None, 'connect_nd': None, 'child_nd': [], 'parent_nd': None, u'control_shape': 0, 'component_index': 0, 'component_name': u'Test'}]}

{nt.RootOpMetaNode(u'M_ROOT_op_0_METAND1'): [{'component_type': u'single_control', 'component_side': u'L', 'main_op_nd_ws_matrix': Matrix([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]), 'sub_op_nd_ws_matrix': [], 'connection_types': [u'translate', u'rotate', u'scale'], 'ik_spaces_ref': None, 'connect_nd': None, 'child_nd': [], 'parent_nd': None, u'control_shape': 0, 'component_index': 1, 'component_name': u'Mom'}]}
```

And here the wrong result after I append them to a list:

```
[{nt.RootOpMetaNode(u'M_ROOT_op_0_METAND'): [{'component_type': u'single_control', 'component_side': u'L', 'main_op_nd_ws_matrix': Matrix([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]), 'sub_op_nd_ws_matrix': [], 'connection_types': [u'translate', u'rotate', u'scale'], 'ik_spaces_ref': None, 'connect_nd': None, 'child_nd': [], 'parent_nd': None, u'control_shape': 0, 'component_index': 1, 'component_name': u'Mom'}]}, {nt.RootOpMetaNode(u'M_ROOT_op_0_METAND1'): [{'component_type': u'single_control', 'component_side': u'L', 'main_op_nd_ws_matrix': Matrix([[1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 1.0, 0.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 1.0, 0.0], [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]]), 'sub_op_nd_ws_matrix': [], 'connection_types': [u'translate', u'rotate', u'scale'], 'ik_spaces_ref': None, 'connect_nd': None, 'child_nd': [], 'parent_nd': None, u'control_shape': 0, 'component_index': 1, 'component_name': u'Mom'}]}]
```

Here is the metod which create the list:

```
def get_operators_meta_data_from_god_node(self):
    """
    Collect the operators meta data from all root meta nodes in the scene.

    Return:
        List: Filled with a dictionary for each root_meta_nd.
        [{"root_meta_nd":pmc.PyNode(), "meta_data":List}]

    """
    result = []
    # get the god meta node from scene.
    self.get_god_meta_nd_from_scene()
    if self.god_meta_nd:
        # get all other meta nodes from scene.
        all_meta_nodes = self.god_meta_nd.list_meta_nodes()
        # get all root meta nodes from all meta nodes.
        all_root_nodes = [
            root
            for root in all_meta_nodes
            if root.attr(constants.META_TYPE).get() == constants.META_TYPE_A
        ]
        # iterate about all root nodes and collect the meta data from it.
        for root_meta_node in all_root_nodes:
            # Gives back a dictionary with meta data from root node.
            temp = self.get_operators_meta_data_from_root_meta_node(
                root_meta_node)
            # Append the meta data dictonary to the result list.
            result.append(temp)
    return result
```

Can anybody help me please? It's driving me nuts :-(

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Putting two dictionaries into one list will not, by itself, change the keys or values of either. There must be something else going on in your code, probably in a different place than you're looking. Please post a minimal complete example that shows the problem.

Comment: By the way, the most likely explanation is that both of your outer dictionaries (the ones starting `{nt.RootOpMetaNode`...) contain refer to the SAME inner dictionary (the one starting `{'component_type':`...).

Comment: add your code containing imports and lines that gives error, so that we can reproduce your error

Comment: Thx a lot guys for the quick answer! I put the method which produce the list into the description!

Comment: @JohannesWolz, you updated your answer, it seems that your function is defined inside a class, what you should share when you are asking a question, is a minimal reproducible code, meaning if I copy paste the code in your question, the code should only gives error about your problem, not anything else. here you used other functions you defined in your class, without mentioning it in your code here.

Comment: @ShoaibMirzaei I understand but it will be hard to make this because it is now really big the framework! I will try to isolate it! And maybe during that i will find the problem! Stay tuned and thx